# Python Pandas - Using to_sql to write large data frames in chunks

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm using Pandas' `to_sql` function to write to MySQL, which is timing out due to large frame size (1M rows, 20 columns).

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Is there a more official way to chunk through the data and write rows in blocks?  I've written my own code, which seems to work.  I'd prefer an official solution though.  Thanks!

```
def write_to_db(engine, frame, table_name, chunk_size):

    start_index = 0
    end_index = chunk_size if chunk_size < len(frame) else len(frame)

    frame = frame.where(pd.notnull(frame), None)
    if_exists_param = 'replace'

    while start_index != end_index:
        print "Writing rows %s through %s" % (start_index, end_index)
        frame.iloc[start_index:end_index, :].to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, if_exists=if_exists_param)
        if_exists_param = 'append'

        start_index = min(start_index + chunk_size, len(frame))
        end_index = min(end_index + chunk_size, len(frame))

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://...') #database details omited
write_to_db(engine, frame, 'retail_pendingcustomers', 20000)
```

Comment: fwiw, i've had to do this exact thing.

Comment: There is no official solution at the moment, but we would certainly accept a patch to implement this (there is an issue about chunksize for `read_sql` (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2908), you can always open one for this).

Comment: I created an issue.  @joris- if you wouldn't mind please add a comment there and back me up :).  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7347

Comment: Why don't you just export the data as a csv file (it has to be in the format of the table) and then use the load data infile command?

Answer (score 31):

Update: this functionality has been merged in pandas master and will be released in 0.15 (probably end of september), thanks to @artemyk! See https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8062

So starting from 0.15, you can specify the `chunksize` argument and e.g. simply do:

```
df.to_sql('table', engine, chunksize=20000)
```

Comment: perfect, it save my day!

Answer (score 1):

There is beautiful idiomatic function chunks provided in answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

In your case you can use this function like this:

```
def chunks(l, n):
""" Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
"""
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
         yield l.iloc[i:i+n]

def write_to_db(engine, frame, table_name, chunk_size):
    for idx, chunk in enumerate(chunks(frame, chunk_size)):
        if idx == 0:
            if_exists_param = 'replace':
        else:
            if_exists_param = 'append'
        chunk.to_sql(con=engine, name=table_name, if_exists=if_exists_param)
```

Only drawback that it doesn't support slicing second index in iloc function.